# Как использовать разделитель

Tags: java

**Задача**: достать из файла корректные данные. Корректные - это фамилия, зарплата и номер департамента. Все данные разделены либо слешем и произвольным количеством пробелов, либо произвольным количеством пробелов.
Также необходимо обработать ошибки, мы не должны доставать строки, в которых после знака "." в зарплате идёт более трёх чисел. Пустые строки, строки без фамилии, департамента - не нужны.

**Файл с данными**:

```
    Ситов /13000.1234134/Первый - невалидно, больше 3 цифр после точки в зп - 1234134, максимум 123 должно быть
    Курбян -13000.123/Второй - невалидный, есть минус в числе
    Кошкин 13000.123/Четвёртый- валидный, потому что фио, цифры, департамент - подходят по условию
    43242/13424/Третий - невалидный, вместо фио цифры
    Жестков/13424/43242- невалидный, вместо департамента цифры
    Петровна/привет/Третий - невалидный, вместо зп цифры
    Иванович/-10000/Третий -невалидно, есть минус у зп
     / 132/ Четвертый - невалидно, ничего нет на месте фио и зп из 3 цифр быть не может, минимум от 5 цифр
    Петров/10000/Пятый - валидно
    Иванов/30000/ШЕСТОЙ -валидно
    Сидоров/20000/Седьмой - валидно
    Пушкин/40000/Восьмой - валидно
```

**Как я пытался сделать**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/VGilenko/Desktop/file.txt"), "CP1251"));

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.trim().length() != 0) {
                String[] words = s.split("/");
                for (String element : words) {
                    System.out.println(element);
                }
            }
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Файл не был найден, нужно скорректировать путь");
    }
}
```

**Вывод моего приложения**:

```
Ситов 
13000.1234134
Первый
Курбян -13000.123
Второй
Иванович
-10000
Третий
 
 132
 Четвертый
Петров
10000
Пятый
Иванов
30000
ШЕСТОЙ
Сидоров
20000
Седьмой
Пушкин
40000
Восьмой
```

**Проблема:**
Понимаю, что программа проверяет на пустоту строк, но мне этого недостаточно, как мне ещё добавить условия, которые необходимы? Допустим, чтобы была проверка на пустые ячейки, например, когда фамилии нет и необходимо эту строку убрать. Нужно ли добавлять `s.trim().length() == 0)` в `if`, потому что если убрать, то он пишет "not a statement" и предлагает `Exctract side effect`.

Comment: убрать пробелы - дело нехитрое. вопрос в разделителе / - это единственный корректный разделитель либо могут быть другие, потому как во втором случае эта строка Курбян -13000.123/Второй вполне валидна?

Comment: По какому правилу разделяются колонки? либо / либо пробел? Может второй слеш также отсутствовать?

Comment: Да, либо /, либо пробел, второй слеш тоже может отсутствовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете создать отдельную функцию, которая будет проверять каждую строку на соответствие. Например так:

```java
public static boolean isLineOkay(String line){
    String[] parts = line.split("/");
    if(parts.length != 3){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
        if (parts[i].trim().isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        if (i == 1 && !parts[i].trim().matches("\\d+\\.?\\d{0,3}")){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

и проверять каждую строчку. В случае `true` дальше ее обрабатывать в соов-е с Вашим заданием.

Например

```java
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(isLineOkay(s)){
        // .. обрабатываем как-то
        // .. например отправляем ее в обработчик
    }
    // .. здесь ничего нет, поэтому
    // .. если строчка не пройдет проверку
    // .. ничего не произойдет. Мы просто
    // .. переходим к следующей
}
```

**Более сложный вариант** предполагает использование регулярок для парсинга. Вот пример:

```
package click.webelement.so;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputs[] = {
                "Ситов /13000.1234134/Первый",
                "Курбян -13000.123/Второй",
                "Кошкин 13000.123/Четвёртый",
                "43242/13424/Третий",
                "Жестков/13424/43242",
                "Петровна/привет/Третий",
                "Иванович/-10000/Третий",
                "/ 132/ Четвертый",
                "Петров/10000/Пятый",
                "Иванов/30000/ШЕСТОЙ",
                "Сидоров/20000/Седьмой",
                "Пушкин/40000/Восьмой",
                " Пушкин / 40000   Восьмой"
        };
        for (String input: inputs){
            String parts[] = isLineOkay(input);
            if(parts != null){
                System.out.println("Parsed data: " + Arrays.asList(parts));
            }
        }
    }

    public static String[] isLineOkay(String line){
        final String PATTERN = "^\\s*?([А-Яа-яЁё]+)\\s*?(?:\\/\\s*?)?(\\d+\\.?\\d{0,3})\\s*?(?:\\/\\s*?)?([А-Яа-яЁё]+)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
        String[] parts = new String[3];
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if(matcher.matches()){
            parts[0] = matcher.group(1);
            parts[1] = matcher.group(2);
            parts[2] = matcher.group(3);
            return parts;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
Parsed data: [Кошкин, 13000.123, Четвёртый]
Parsed data: [Петров, 10000, Пятый]
Parsed data: [Иванов, 30000, ШЕСТОЙ]
Parsed data: [Сидоров, 20000, Седьмой]
Parsed data: [Пушкин, 40000, Восьмой]
Parsed data: [Пушкин, 40000, Восьмой]
```

**P.S.** - Регулярка разбирает строчку на куски позволяя частям быть окруженными любым количеством пробелов и разделяться либо слешами либо пробелами либо вообще ничем. Т.е. текстчислотекст тоже сгодиться.

Comment: Если проходит, то всё понятно, мы должны с ней работать, потому что отправит нам true. А как обработать, если нам прислало false? Как пропустить строку, пытался сделать так, но не работает, выводит всё `while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                boolean decision = isLineOkay(s);
                if (decision = false) {
                skip();
                } else {
                    String[] parts = s.split("/");
                    //здесь вывод по словам
                    }
                }
            }` Но как оказалось, это не пропускает строку.

Comment: Оберните в `if` и просто не делайте ничего если `false`. См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что это называется регулярные выражения? Что вы показали - всё изучил, а вот как мне Курбяна можно обработать (третья строка)? Спасибо, что помогаете.

Comment: Третья строка валидная?

Comment: Да, всё верно, подобные строки являются валидными. Где есть корректное написание фио, цифр, департамента. ФИО в целом всегда валидно, из соображений должно быть слово. Цифр - это без минуса должна быть зп, а также максимум 3 цифры после точки. Департамент - должно быть слово.

Comment: Добавьте примеров в вопросе с указанием какой валидный какой нет и почему. Я поправлю свой ответ

Comment: Про Курбяна прошу прощения, он невалидный, там действительно минус стоит, сглупил. Сейчас добавлю информации в пост.

Comment: Поправил пост, указал с пояснениями.

Comment: Смотрите обновление

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так?

```
 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
            String[] words = s.split("/");
            for (String element : words) {
                if(!element.trim().isEmpty())
                   System.out.println(element);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, единственным адекватным решением данного вопроса являются регулярные выражения. Без них проверка сроки станет гораздо более неудобной. Вот оптимальное решение.

```java
String regex = "[А-Яа-яЁёA-Za-z]+";
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!(s = s.trim()).isEmpty()) {
        String[] strings = s.split("\\s*/\\s*|\\s+");
        if (strings.length < 3)
            continue;
        if (!(strings[0].matches(regex) && strings[2].matches(regex)))
            continue;
        if (!strings[1].matches("\\d{5}(\\.\\d{1,3})?"))
            continue;
        System.out.println(strings[0] + " " + strings[1] + " " + strings[2]);
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы разделителем был только символ `/` и ничего более, четвёртую строчку надо будет написать так:
`String[] strings = s.split("/");`

Если вы хотите, чтобы выводилась причина, вы можете сделать так:

```java
if (strings.length < 3) {
    System.out.println("Строка `" + s + "` имеет неверное количество слов");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Могли бы подсказать как исправить, чтобы разделителем являлся только / и ничего больше, чтобы была возможность сделать такой вариант: Кошкин Иван Иванович/1234/Пятый  Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы, если строка по какому-то пункту не проходила по условию, то выводилась причина.Пример: строка номер 5 имеет больше, чем нужно чисел после точки. Потому что я вот так делаю: `if (strings.length < 3)
                        continue;
                    else
                        System.out.println("Строка номер " + count + " имеет неверное количество слов");` и выводит не то, что нужно

Comment: Верно понял: чтобы разделителем был только "/", то такой вариант изменённого кода подойдёт `"String[] strings = s.split("\\s*/\\s*+");"` или нужно вот так? `"\\s*/+"`. Но как тогда изменить код, чтобы Кошкин Иван Иванович/1234/Пятый тоже мог пройти проверку?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, была проблема, что фио не вмещается, обновил строку `String regex = "[А-Яа-яЁёA-Za-z\\s]+";` Пробелы не обрабатывали, из-за чего строку считал некорректной.